# Can we add an href attribute on div tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I have a div tag and it has a link tag inside it as shown in the code. The link works only when I click on it.  But I want to code in such a way that even when I click on div tag, it should go to the link. Please help as I am a beginner in javascript.

```
<div id="blockbuilding">
  <a id="@data.bbuildingid" href="@Url.Action("Overview","Overview", new{BuildingId=@data.buildingID})" class="buildingAnchor""> @data.buildingName </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

        $("#blockbuilding").click(
            function () {
                AlertSave();
            }            
        );
    });

function AlertSave() {
   alert("Alert Message OnClick");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="blockbuilding">
  <a id="@data.bbuildingid" href="@Url.Action("Overview","Overview", new{BuildingId=@data.buildingID})" class="buildingAnchor""> @data.buildingName </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Where should I include the jquery code ?

Comment: you may apply jquery in function AlertSave or  you can apply directly in click function of div

Comment: No I meant where should I write the $(document).ready(function() ?

Comment: in html header tag <script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function()  ); </script>. you can do like this

Comment: Please tel me where I should write the function definition ? Should it be in the same cshtml file?

Comment: you can add this function in html for eg:- <html><title>URL Test</title><head></script><script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function () {

        $("#blockbuilding").click(
            function () {
                AlertSave();
            }            
        );
    });

function AlertSave() {
   alert("Alert Message");
}</script></head><body></body> <form id="form1"><div id="blockbuilding">
  <a id="@data.bbuildingid" href="@Url.Action("Overview","Overview", new{BuildingId=@data.buildingID})" class="buildingAnchor""> @data.buildingName </a>
</div> </form></html>